# How to boost a WebView in android

Tags: android, webview

I have been using a WebView in my android app, but it performs very slowly and does not charge all the webs it should. I would like to know a  way of making a webView quicker. 
I have tried to instal the actualization of webView in my device but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the real problem is the speed of the site you call in your webview. Anyhow, a good way to improve page's loading speed in webviews is to enable Cache, like this:

```
WebSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
WebSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
WebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Keep in mind that by doing this the webview will not update immediately every page if anything changes.

Comment: I`ve done what you said but when installing the app the phone shows the "restart" screen and the app does not run, I don´t know if you know why this happens.